microk8s ingress addon: cannot change `allow-snippet-annotations` setting
I use the ingress addon provided by microk8s.
$ microk8s version
MicroK8s v1.31.1 revision 7244

I want to use nginx snippets for my ingress configuration.
The motivation behind that is to achieve what the OP attempted in this SO question.
By default, ingress is configured to not use the snippets.
Others reported seeing an error after using the configuration without enabling it first.
However, I did not encounter any such error.
Nonetheless, the annotations seem to be ignored.
I test them this way, and I can still access the resource:
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: foo-ingress-bar
  namespace: foo
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: deny all;

I had tried many different variations of the snippet, and also of the configuration-snippet, to no avail before I learnt about the allow-snippet-annotations configuration option.
I tried editting the ingress config map.
$ k get configmap -n ingress
NAME                                DATA   AGE
kube-root-ca.crt                    1      2d18h
nginx-ingress-tcp-microk8s-conf     1      2d18h
nginx-ingress-udp-microk8s-conf     0      2d18h
nginx-load-balancer-microk8s-conf   0      2d18h

$ k edit configmap nginx-ingress-tcp-microk8s-conf -n ingress

And added a new section which saved ok.
data:
  allow-snippet-annotations: "true"

However, when I view logs of any ingress pod (listed with k get pod -n ingress), I get the following error:
I1028 14:27:38.275743       7 event.go:377] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress", Name:"nginx-ingress-tcp-microk8s-conf", UID:"a521e9e9-add9-417b-938e-54463edfedaf", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"299883", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' ConfigMap ingress/nginx-ingress-tcp-microk8s-conf
W1028 14:27:38.284327       7 controller.go:477] "allow-snippet-annotations" is not a valid TCP port number

I did not find an answer to this.
What are some ways to enable snippets with microk8s?
Why is it expecting "a valid TCP port number"?

You should edit the nginx-load-balancer-microk8s-conf configmap, not the nginx-ingress-tcp-microk8s-conf.
Regards
